# How to submit a form with the label values?

Tags: html

I'm new to web development

I want to submit a form with the label names.

I mean in my `html` page i have shown some details of a person. Those details are showing using labels. After clicking submit button i want to submit that details to another HTML page

Anyone have a Idea how to do that?

Comment: How are you creating the labels?

Answer (score 1):

Use the concept of **hidden fields**.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: a lot of us have stopped referencing w3schools. If you want to know why: w3fools.com

Comment: That's alright. I just gave a suggestion. If you want you can refer any other site of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not style input fields to look like labels? You could even stop them from being editable. That way a form submit will ensure they get posted.

Comment: Because that's going to break accessibility software, which assumes that something marked up as an input field is an input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden field with labels

```
input type="hidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give You an example of my way of solving this:

I declare two html elements as this:

```
<label name="importe_label" id="importe_label" />
<input type="hidden" id="importe" name="importe" value=""/>
```

Then, for example, I set both of them with jQuery:

```
$("#importe_gravado").val(99.99);
$("#importe_gravado_label").text(99.99);
```

So, when I submit the form, I get the value I need in back-end (In the "importe" parameter, in this case).

I don't know if is this the best way, but It works! :)

Hope It helps anybody. Best regards!